How do I order Dagger multibindings?
For example, there's need to provide a set of bindings somewhere:
class Farm @Inject constructor(
    private val animals: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards Animal>,
){
    
    init {
        animals.forEach { feed(it) }
    }
}

And the bindings (that may be in different gradle modules):
//module A
@Binds
@IntoSet
abstract fun goat(goat: Goat): Animal

//module B
@Provides
@IntoSet
fun cow(): Animal = Cow(...)

How do we ensure the correct order of the bindings (and feed the goats first)?
In Spring Boot, for example, there's order annotation for that
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order
I could use IntoMap instead with int keys, but it's not that elegant in the end.

So Dagger multibinds by default work on sets, not on lists.  Sets have no ordering, and two walks of a set are not guaranteed to have the same order.
You can instead provide a Map multibinding.  In this form, instead of injecting a set, it injects a Map<String, Type>.  You could use that to provide an ordering if you use a string key that is sortable (such as using a number and sorting on the toInt of it).  That would require you to enact some code discipline though, as the compiler would not enforce it.
The way to use Map multibinding is like this:
  @Provides @IntoMap
  @StringKey("1")
  fun cow(): Animal = Cow()

Then you inject it as a Map<String, Animal> instead of animal.  To get the values in order, you'd use
class Farm @Inject constructor(
private val animals: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards Animal>,
){
init {
    //sort the entries by the integer value of the key, then feed them in order
    animals.entries.sortedBy {it.key.toInt()}.forEach {
        feed(it.value)
    }
}

}
